# Accessing the Id parameter in VF page passing it to Javascript function

Tags: visualforce

How to access the Id from URL in visualforce, i want to pass that Id to javascript function to load my page, please help.

Answer (score 6):

You can access it vial $CurrentPage global variable avaialble in visualforce for e.g.

```
{!$CurrentPage.parameters.relatedId}
```

in JS

```
 var tempValue = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.relatedId}';
```

For more details refer:- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_global_currentpage.htm

Comment: Thanks Anshul, can you provice snippet how to pass this to javascript function. Thanks in Advance

Comment: you can simply assign it to a javascript variable
var tempValue = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.relatedId}';

Answer (score 2):

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
} 

/apex/test?id=1
var id = getUrlParameter('id');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use can access URL parameters directly in VF page using $CurrentPage global variable.
For getting ID from URL parameters use

```
{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}
```

You can get ID in Javascript using above syntax :

```
var Id = '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}';
console.log(Id);
```

Comment: there is already an ans to above question with same approach. Can you pls tell me how you are ans providing more info?